# Returning incorrect position inside getView()

Tags: android

My problem is after I have six or more entrys in my listview the getView method starts to give me the wrong position of the items, because my listview after scrolling is recycled. My question is how can I get right position after scrolling. I studied this problem in the similar qestion, but I can't still solve it. Can you someone help me please?

```
public class LayoutPreference extends DialogPreference {
private String mValue = "1";//default
private int mClickedDialogEntryIndex;
GridView gridView;
ArrayList<LayoutConfiguration> gridArray = new ArrayList<LayoutConfiguration>();
LayoutPreferenceViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
private boolean mValueSet;
private String[] mEntryValues;
private String[] mEntries;
Button btnConfirm;

public LayoutPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.imglayout_grid);
    setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.imglayout_grid_widget);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    final ImageView box = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pref_widget_box);

    gridArray.clear();
    for ( LayoutConfiguration layoutConfiguration : LayoutConfiguration.getLayoutConfigurations()) {
        gridArray.add(layoutConfiguration);
    }

    for ( LayoutConfiguration layoutConfiguration : gridArray) {
        if ( mValue != null && mValue.equals(layoutConfiguration.getId())) {

            box.setImageBitmap(layoutConfiguration.genImage(105, 75));
            if(layoutConfiguration.getId()=="conf_2.1"||layoutConfiguration.getId()=="conf_2"){
            box.setRotation(0);
            }else{
                box.setRotation(180);
            }
        }
    }
    box.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    setEntryValues();

    int index = findIndexOfValue(getSharedPreferences().getString(getKey(), "1"));

    ViewGroup rootLayout = (ViewGroup) view;
    gridView = (GridView) rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    customGridAdapter = new LayoutPreferenceViewAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.imglayout_row_grid, gridArray, index, new ItemSelectedListener());


    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    btnConfirm = (Button) rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.confirmBtn);
    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            save();     
        }
    });


    super.onBindDialogView(view);
}

private void setEntryValues() {
    mEntryValues = new String[gridArray.size()];
    for ( int i = 0; i < gridArray.size(); i++)
        mEntryValues[i] = gridArray.get(i).getId();
    mEntries = new String[gridArray.size()];
    for ( int i = 0; i < gridArray.size(); i++)
        mEntries[i] = gridArray.get(i).getId();
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    // Always persist/notify the first time.
    final boolean changed = !TextUtils.equals(mValue, value);
    if (changed || !mValueSet) {
        mValue = value;
        mValueSet = true;
        persistString(value);
        if (changed) {
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
    setValue(restoreValue ? getPersistedString(mValue) : (String) defaultValue);
}

public String getValue() {
    return mValue; 
}

private int getValueIndex() {
    return findIndexOfValue(mValue);
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);

    mClickedDialogEntryIndex = getValueIndex();

    builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);
}

public int findIndexOfValue(String value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gridArray.size(); i++) {
        if (gridArray.get(i).getId().equals(value)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public class ItemSelectedListener {

    public void itemSelected( int index) {
        if ( mClickedDialogEntryIndex >= 0) {
            CheckedTextView chk = (CheckedTextView) ((RelativeLayout) gridView.getChildAt(mClickedDialogEntryIndex)).findViewById(R.id.item_chk);
            if ( chk != null)
                chk.setChecked(false);
        }

        mClickedDialogEntryIndex = index;
        mValue = mEntryValues[index];
        CheckedTextView chk = (CheckedTextView) ((RelativeLayout) gridView.getChildAt(mClickedDialogEntryIndex)).findViewById(R.id.item_chk);
        if ( chk != null)
            chk.setChecked(true);
    }
}


private void save() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor();
    editor.putString( Preferences.SETTINGS_LAYOUT, mValue);
    editor.commit();
    callChangeListener( mValue);

    LayoutPreference.this.onClick(getDialog(), DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    getDialog().dismiss();
}
```

}

```
public class LayoutPreferenceViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LayoutConfiguration> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
int index;
ArrayList<LayoutConfiguration> data ;
ItemSelectedListener listener;

public LayoutPreferenceViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<LayoutConfiguration> data, int index, ItemSelectedListener listener) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.index = index;
    this.listener = listener;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.chk = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_chk);
        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();   
    }

    holder.imageItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.itemSelected(position);
        }
    });
    holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listener.itemSelected(position);
        }
    });

    LayoutConfiguration item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.genImage( 140, 100));
    return row;

}

static class RecordHolder {
    CheckedTextView chk;
    ImageView imageItem;

}
```

http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=2014071811.png

and

http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=201407nin.png

After call Log in GetView method.

```
Log.i("getView ","Position " + position + " View " + row);

07-18 11:59:43.694: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View null
07-18 11:59:43.704: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@410f00e8
07-18 11:59:43.704: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@410f00e8
07-18 11:59:43.714: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@410f00e8
07-18 11:59:43.714: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@410f00e8
07-18 11:59:43.714: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@410f00e8
07-18 11:59:43.734: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@410f00e8
07-18 11:59:43.744: I/getView(2954): Position 1 View null
07-18 11:59:43.755: I/getView(2954): Position 2 View null
07-18 11:59:43.785: I/getView(2954): Position 3 View null
07-18 11:59:43.805: I/getView(2954): Position 4 View null
07-18 11:59:43.815: I/getView(2954): Position 5 View null
07-18 11:59:43.875: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View null
07-18 11:59:43.905: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@4100b838
07-18 11:59:43.905: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@4100b838
07-18 11:59:43.905: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@4100b838
07-18 11:59:43.915: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@4100b838
07-18 11:59:43.915: I/getView(2954): Position 0 View android.widget.RelativeLayout@4100b838
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    RecordHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.chk = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_chk);
        holder.imageItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.itemSelected((int) v.getTag());
            }
        });
        holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listener.itemSelected((int) v.getTag());
            }
        });
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();   
    }

    holder.imageItem.setTag(position);
    holder.chk.setTag(position);

    LayoutConfiguration item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.genImage( 140, 100));
    return row;

}
```

I don't see necessary to put final modifier for position variable.

Also, you can change the name of the view which the method receives and avoid create another view "View row = convertView;".

Using ".inflate(layoutId, null)" is a bad practise, because you are not telling to the system which is the parent of the view and "layout_..." attributes in xml won't work. More information here: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

With my modifications I believe the code will save correctly the position for each list item inside the list view.

Comment: Thanks for really fast answer and information, but if i started scrolling, I get position 6 and 7, and if I clicked on the position 4, it selects the position number 6

Comment: I have modified the method, try again now @Zdenek

Comment: it still doesn't work properly, I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think It would be useful to print the position variable in Logcat. Put Log.e("position", String.valueOf(position)) in the different parts of the method (if, onclick...). To avoid many Logcat outputs you can remove some elements of the list or put a condition.